Nested case statements in SQL Server
I am trying to execute the nested case statements that would get executed when the conditions in initial case statement is not executed. I am getting the error "invalid column name - initial_case_output". Any suggestions would be appreciated.
SELECT
    ZTYPE_TRF, 
    CASE WHEN type = '4' THEN N'ABC'
         WHEN type = '3' THEN N'DEF'
    END AS initial_case_output,
    (CASE 
       WHEN b.SC = 'D2' then N'DEF'
       WHEN b.SC = 'D5' then N'GHI'
     ELSE initial_case_output
    END) AS ZTYPE_NEW
 FROM report a left join  table2 b
 on a.BA = b.BA;


You can't reference a column alias from the same SELECT list.

Sounds like you would do better to remove those CASE expressions and rather join a mapping table where you assign the desired string to the type and/or to the SC column.

CASE expression (not statement).

If you wrap a calculation up in a CROSS APPLY, you can then reference the result elsewhere in your query (without duplicating code).
SELECT
    ZTYPE_TRF, 
    CA.initial_case_output,
    (CASE 
       WHEN b.SC = 'D2' then N'DEF'
       WHEN b.SC = 'D5' then N'GHI'
     ELSE CA.initial_case_output
    END) AS ZTYPE_NEW
FROM report a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.BA = b.BA
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN type = '4' THEN N'ABC'
            WHEN type = '3' THEN N'DEF'
            END AS initial_case_output
) CA;

Or even:
SELECT
    ZTYPE_TRF, 
    CA1.initial_case_output,
    CA2.ZTYPE_NEW
FROM report a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.BA = b.BA
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN type = '4' THEN N'ABC'
            WHEN type = '3' THEN N'DEF'
            END AS initial_case_output
) CA1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN b.SC = 'D2' then N'DEF'
            WHEN b.SC = 'D5' then N'GHI'
            ELSE CA1.initial_case_output
            END AS ZTYPE_NEW
) CA2;

The latter separates complex expressions from the final select list, which may improve readability.

The error is because the CASE statement is trying to access initial_case_output before it is defined. You will need to break down the query into subquery to access the alias.
Alias defined in the SELECT clause are not available in the same SELECT clause.
Here is a better way to solve the problem:
SELECT
a.ZTYPE_TRF,
initial_case_output,
(CASE
    WHEN b.SC = 'D2' THEN N'DEF'
    WHEN b.SC = 'D5' THEN N'GHI'
    ELSE initial_case_output
END) AS ZTYPE_NEW
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ZTYPE_TRF,
            CASE
                WHEN type = '4' THEN N'ABC'
                WHEN type = '3' THEN N'DEF'
            END AS initial_case_output
        FROM
            report
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.BA = b.BA;

PS. I don't know about the exact variables and tables you are using but this is the general idea to tackle the problem.

You can repeat case
SELECT
    ZTYPE_TRF, 
    CASE WHEN type = '4' THEN N'ABC'
         WHEN type = '3' THEN N'DEF'
    END AS initial_case_output,
    (CASE 
       WHEN b.SC = 'D2' then N'DEF'
       WHEN b.SC = 'D5' then N'GHI'
     ELSE
       CASE WHEN type = '4' THEN N'ABC'
            WHEN type = '3' THEN N'DEF'
       END 
    END) AS ZTYPE_NEW
 FROM report a left join  table2 b
 on a.BA = b.BA;

